# Is it a good idea to hash a string and use it as a passphrase?

Tags: hash, truecrypt, passphrase, luks

Is it a good idea to hash(SHA-512/whirlpool) some simple memorable string and use it for passphrase(for LUKS/TrueCrypt container), instead of using just a string like **t4k#La93Fs(5w5)** as a passphrase?

Answer (score 1):

- If this means you're effectively using the same passphase everywhere, then: this is a very bad idea.
- If you're generating a new password each time anyway (as you should), why not use an actual random string, like in your example?

——

Also, in real world usage, a sha512 hash will be too long for many sites (that is: you can't set a password that long)

Comment: I didn't mention but the passphrase is for LUKS/TrueCrypt container.

Comment: Basically, with your method there would be a theoretical increase in security as the hash will be longer than a "simple passphrase", but in practice a "correct horse battery staple" (http://xkcd.com/936/) type passphase is just as strong, and doesn't require an extra tool to hash your phrase every time you need the password.